# How to keep a Java class in memory during the app execution?

Tags: java, class, object, variables

I know it's basics, but I really don't remember how to do it.

1. In my `MainActivity` I fill a class `Util` with data I get from my
   database.
2. And, what I wanna do is to be able to access the data of this util class from other classes.

For example, I'm in random class and *I wanna get an attribute* from `Util`. How do I do it? Considering that I can't call a `new Util()`... because it's gonna clear the info I have in that util class. In summary, how to keep an object in memory to be accessed from everywhere?

Comment: make the class static

Comment: Or you can just keep a reference to the class, and retrieve it.  Typically you do have to at some point use a static method, but often it's better to use instances as much as possible.  However Dependency Injection is an alternative and works also.

Comment: how do I turna class into static? It gives me an error if I try something like "public static class Myclass"

Comment: Are these other random classes created in the `MainActivity`?

Comment: May be this Oracle's Java tutorial on [Creating Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) has information you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Make the object you want to access static. You should read a basic Java tutorial about the static keyword, because the use of it will potentially cause issues when you start dealing with more advanced topics like threads and memory management. (Static ArrayLists are the *worst*.)

So you have some class `Util`:

```
public class Util {
    private static Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

    // assume you have some logic to populate data

    // This method is static, so you don't need an instance of Util to access it
    public static Map<String, String> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Static methods don't require an instance in order to be invoked -- you invoke them against the class itself.

To access `data` in the example above from anywhere in your code:

```
Map<String, String> theData = Util.getData(); // called against the class
```

You could, of course, new up an instance of Util (eg. `Util myUtil = new Util()`) and then call `myUtil.getData()` -- but there is no difference and your IDE will warn you that you're doing this if you try.